# Feeding Batch an <enter> keystroke

Tags: batch-processing

In a batch file containing the following:

```
cd .\10%%_AltApp\
call Process_UZ_Output.exe
sleep 2
cd ..

cd .\10%%_FalFld\
call Process_UZ_Output.exe
sleep 2
cd ..

...(repeated many more time)...
```

the batch process itself is temporarily hung up by the fact that when "Process_UZ_Output.exe" completes its task, it is waiting for the user to hit .  I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the batch file such that the flow of the batch file will continue without the user having to hit enter everytime Process_UZ_Output.exe completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `START` instead of `CALL`:

```
START Process_UZ_Output.exe /B
```